# ios webview stream background mode

Tags: ios, iphone, background

I have a problem with my app when it going in background.
I have this error 3 minutes after the app went in background:

> Background task expired while holding WebKit ProcessAssertion.

Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain more? Do you have issue your webview task has finished when app goes in background or you want to finish the task when app stops in background mode?

Comment: Can you provide some code on how you are streaming and what you have tried? Any links you have followed?

Answer (score 0):

Delegate "applicationDidEnterBackground:"

Method has approximately 5 seconds to finish any tasks and return.

If you perform any task on main thread that take more then 5 second..
Then you get error.

Try that method in background thread like this.

```
-(void) method
{

UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier  taskId = 0;

    taskId = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        taskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

// Perform your task


   }];


}
```

Answer (score -2):

just add a row to the plist file labeled "Required Background Modes" and under that set item 0's value to "App plays audio".
[image]